# server boots into read-only file system after power outage

Tags: server, ssh, login, startup, logging

ok obi wan you're my only hope.  my power went out recently and when it came back on, when I login to my ubuntu server I get the message below:

```
Unable to setup logging. [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/log/landscape/sysinfo.log'
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo exited with return code 1 
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: 31: /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: cannot create /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available: Read-only file system mktemp: failed to create file via template '/var/lib/update-notifeir/tmp.xxxxxxxxxx': Read-only file system run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/95-hwe-eol exited with return code 1 /user/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: 33: /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: cannot create /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: Read-only file system
```

also I'm no longer able to connect to the internet from my ubuntu server.  I can still ssh into the server remotely from my laptop while I'm on my home network, but I can't ping anything from my ubuntu server once I've ssh in.  And just to make things interesting, sudo has also stopped working for me.  Does anyone have a suggestion what the issue might be, and how to fix it?

Comment: You've not told us what Ubuntu Server product you're asking about, nor what release of that product. If it hasn't already correctly booted after a power loss; I'd recommend booting *live* media & performing *file-system checks* on your file-systems, where if any errors are detected & fixed - I expect normal operation after that.  I also check drive health too (*ie. SMART, on any problem, including power*) as I think that's useful.  Do not file-system check commands (`fsck` etc) vary on details you didn't provide; esp. file-systems involved.

Comment: Also, look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @guiverc sorry it's taken me so long to reply.  I'm running ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  I'm a little confused, you're suggesting to run file-system checks but you don't want me to run the fsck command?  I thought fsck was the file-system check, is there some other command I should run?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is EOSS (*end-of-standard-support*) thus off-topic on this site (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specifically about moving to a *fully supported* release of Ubuntu. Being EOSS, mirrors can drop the release.  Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/

Comment: `fsck` IS the command you run for some file-systems, but on others it'll only report no-issue (*without doing anything to prevent dataloss*).  The command you use is specific to the *file-system* being used (`xfs_check` if using XFS etc)